# Unable to verify message signed by sol-wallet-adapter

Tags: ecdsa, ed25519, solana

Having [created a signed message](https://github.com/project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter#sign-a-message) I'm unsure how to use the resulting signature to verify the message using the publicKey.

My use case is, I'm wanting to use a Solana Wallet to login to an API server with a pattern like:

1. `GET message: String (from API server)`
2. `sign message with privateKey`
3. `POST signature (to API server)`
4. `verify signature with stored publicKey`

I've attempted to use nodeJS `crypto.verify` to decode the signed message on the API side but am a bit out of my depth digging into Buffers and elliptic curves:

```js
// Front-end code
const toHexString = (buffer: Buffer) =>
  buffer.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"), "");

const data = new TextEncoder().encode('message to verify');
const signed = await wallet.sign(data, "hex");
await setLogin({ // sends API post call to backend
  variables: {
    publicAddress: walletPublicKey,
    signature: toHexString(signed.signature),
  },
});

// Current WIP for backend code
const ALGORITHM = "ed25519";
const fromHexString = (hexString) =>
  new Uint8Array(hexString.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16)));
const signature = fromHexString(args.signature);
const nonceUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode('message to verify');
const verified = crypto.verify(
  ALGORITHM,
  nonceUint8,
  `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${user.publicAddress}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`,
  signature
);
console.log("isVerified: ", verified);
```

I'm pretty sure I'm going about this the wrong way and there must be an obvious method I'm missing.

As the space matures I expect a verify function or lib will appear to to consume the output of `const signed = await wallet.sign(data, "hex");`

Something like:

```js
import { VerifyMessage } from '@solana/web3.js';

const verified = VerifyMessage(message, publicKey, signature, 'hex');
```

But after 3 days of pushing hard I'm starting to hit my limits and my brain is failing. Any help or direction where to look much appreciated

Comment: Did you try using Solana's [web3 API](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/transaction.html#verifysignatures) instead ?

Comment: Also, did you try to verify it using the signing example [provided here](https://github.com/project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter#sign-a-message) ?

Comment: ```const data = new TextEncoder().encode('message to verify');
const signed = await wallet.sign(data, "hex");
...
signature: toHexString(signed.signature),```

You're using hex here but serum example shows UTF8

Comment: Also the verification method is questionable.

```const verified = crypto.verify(
  ALGORITHM,
  nonceUint8,
  `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${user.publicAddress}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`,
  signature
);```

a public address and a public key aren't the same. And assuming user.publicAddress is even correct, is it in the right format, e.g. base64?

Comment: Looking at the ETH web3 docs is probably the best way to describe what is trying to be achieved here. The equivalent of the `sign` function is what I'm looking at here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-personal.html?highlight=verify%20message#sign. The distinction being that signing and recovering a message doesn't incur an on chain transaction. You can see the corresponding `ecRecover` function here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-personal.html#ecrecover. You'll also notice that these functions are distinct from `signTransaction` and `sendTransaction`.

Comment: Check an working example https://github.com/enginer/solana-message-sign-verify-example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved with input from the fantastic Project Serum discord devs. High level solution is to use libs that are also used in the sol-wallet-adapter repo, namely `tweetnacl` and `bs58`:

```js
const signatureUint8 = base58.decode(args.signature);
const nonceUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(user?.nonce);
const pubKeyUint8 = base58.decode(user?.publicAddress);

nacl.sign.detached.verify(nonceUint8, signatureUint8, pubKeyUint8)
// true
```

Comment: great! make sure to accept the correct answer here on SO so others know =)

Comment: This saved my life ! Thank you ! I tried for a whole day to do this in PHP but gave up on it, so I had to spin up a small node.js docker that will do only this one thing .... sucks.. does anyone know how to do this in PHP ?

Answer (score 8):

I recommend staying in solana-labs trail and use tweetnacl

spl-token-wallet (sollet.io) signs an arbitrary message with
`nacl.sign.detached(message, this.account.secretKey)`

https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet/blob/9c9f1d48a589218ffe0f54b7d2f3fb29d84f7b78/src/utils/walletProvider/localStorage.js#L65-L67

on the other end, verify is done with
`nacl.sign.detached.verify`

in @solana/web3.js
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/src/transaction.ts#L560

Use `nacl.sign.detached.verify` in your backend and you should be good. I also recommend avoiding any data format manipulation, I am not sure what you were trying to do but if you do verify that each step is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, solana.request will cause error. Use solana.signMessage and base58 encode the signature.

```
var _signature = ''; 
try {
  signedMessage = await window.solana.request({
    method: "signMessage",
    params: {
      message: encodedMessage
    },
  }); 
  _signature = signedMessage.signature; 
} catch (e) { 
  try {
    signedMessage = await window.solana.signMessage(encodedMessage); 
    _signature = base58.encode(signedMessage.signature); 
  } catch (e1) {
    alert(e1.message);
  }
}
// 
try {
  signIn('credentials',
    {
      publicKey: signedMessage.publicKey,
      signature: _signature,
      callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/`
    }
  )
} catch (e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert Uint8Array to string and convert it back to Uint8Array for HTTP communication. I found the `toLocaleString` method of Uint8Array helpful in this case. It outputs comma-separated integers as a string.

```
const signedMessage = await window.solana.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");
const signature = signedMessage.signature.toLocaleString();
```

[image]

And then you can convert it back to Uint8Array with the following code.

```
const signatureUint8 = new Uint8Array(signature.split(",").map(Number));
```

**Edit**

The solution above was working on the desktop but when I tried my code inside the Phantom wallet iOS browser it gave an error. I guess the toLocaleString method is not available in that browser. I found a more solid solution to convert Uint8Array to a comma-separated string

```
Array.apply([], signedMessage.signature).join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Signing and base64 encode:

```js
const data = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(data); // Uint8Array
const signatureBase64 = Buffer.from(signature).toString('base64')
```

Base64 decode and verifying:

```js
const signatureUint8 = new Uint8Array(atob(signature).split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))
const messageUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message)
const pubKeyUint8 = wallet.publicKey.toBytes() // base58.decode(publicKeyAsString)
const result = nacl.sign.detached.verify(messageUint8, signatureUint8, pubKeyUint8) // true or false
```

Full code example: https://github.com/enginer/solana-message-sign-verify-example

Comment: `atob` function is deprecated. For code running using Node.js APIs, converting between base64-encoded strings and binary data should be performed using `Buffer.from(str, 'base64')` and `buf.toString('base64')`