# Verify Phantom signature in C++ server

Tags: c++, cryptography, blockchain, solana, ed25519

I'm building a online game with a Phantom wallet login. My server is written in C++ and I want to make the signature verification there. The connection between client and server is a socket connection sending JSON.

For the client side, I went through the [Phantom documentation](https://docs.phantom.app/). I retrieved the public key as a string and the signature as a uint8array, example values:

- public key: "26qv4GCcx98RihuK3c4T6ozB3J7L6VwCuFVc7Ta2A3Uo"
- signature: [141,47,223,197,8,57,72,178,113,62,233,50,47,234,39,143,169,82,59,190,214,185,25,227,94,68,209,118,231,120,66,224,241,241,168,128,56,63,80,41,219,202,17,191,214,185,91,178,55,126,194,152,157,173,248,212,89,126,128,157,168,119,244,6]

I found that Solana uses ED25519 signature, and I also found [this website](http://ed25519.herokuapp.com/) that implements the algorithm. And after trying multiple different entries to sign a message, I realized that the signature always contains characters that *can be displayed*. Therefore my first question is, why are there *invalid characters* (unable to be displayed) in my signature ? Example with the above signature: "�/���9H�q>�2/�'��R;�ֹ��^D�v�xB�����8?P)����ֹ[�7~�����Y~���w��".

Concerning the server side, I found some libraries to verify the signature:

- https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/tweetnacl.cpp
- https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/

But after multiple attempts, I could not find any valid set (message, public key and signature) that succeed the verification method `int crypto_sign_open(byte *m,word64 *mlen,const byte *sm,word64 n,const byte *pk)`

Therefore, my big question is, how do I verify this signature ? I did not find a proper example verifying a Phantom signature, especially in another language than Javascript.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed verifying this signature. My first mistake was that, for ED25519 signature, the public key has to be 32 bytes. However, the Phantom public key contains 44 bytes. I found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68294363/unable-to-verify-message-signed-by-sol-wallet-adapter) for which one of the answers says that the 44 bytes public key needs to be decoded in base 58 that gives us a 32 bytes key.

Secondly, in the server, the method to use to verify the signature was not the right one. Indeed the right one is: `int crypto_sign_verify_detached(const unsigned char *sig, const unsigned char *m, unsigned long long mlen, const unsigned char *pk)`. The method is described [here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/public-key_signatures#example-detached-mode).

With these two changes, the verification works perfectly!